# c# xml serializable multiple arrayitems

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I having a rather fatuous issue while trying to get my programming to deserialize multiple XmlArrayItem's.

The XML basically looks like this:

```
<Root2>
   <Data2>
     <HOLD>
      ...
     </HOLD>
     <CUST_HOLD>
      ...
     </CUST_HOLD>
   </DATA2>
</ROOT2>
```

And my serializable code like this:

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Root2")]
public class Root2
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray("Data2")]           
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("CUST_HOLD", typeof(CUST_HOLD))]
    public CUST_HOLD[] CUST_HOLD { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("HOLD", typeof(HOLD))]
    public HOLD[] HOLD { get; set; }    

}
```

I tried different configs, but this is the only one that doesn't result in an error.
But the problem is, only the first XmlArrayItem gets processed (in this case CUST_HOLD).
The other remains null, while there should be at least one item within the corresponding array.

Comment: have you tried XmlElement instead?

Comment: @CuongLe You're right, will deal with it now.

Comment: @MUG4N I swapped `XmlArrayItem` with `XmlElement`, if thats what you meant. Unfortunately that gives a InvalidOperationException; There was an error reflecting type 'Root2'. :(

Comment: Let me get this straight...Data2 is the Array Outer Node, and it contains both Hold and Cust_hold entries?  That seems rather...inefficient.  If there's no way to improve that, it might actaully be easier to manually de-serialize the xml's as opposed to trying to get serializer to handle it.  Use some XSL selects to get each node from the the Data2 level and write a parser.

Comment: @Nevyn Well as a matter a fact I just made a change to improve that somewhat inefficient structure. Now I got a seperate Array Outer Node for the the Cust_hold entries, which is named Data3. While the Hold entries still remain in Data2. It seems to work so far..

Answer (score 0):

If you can't write an xsd for it you can't serialise/deserialise it as xml.

That would be a sequence or a desperately poor collection of any in an xsd.

Answer (score 0):

Try With,

**CODE**

**Classes Declaration**

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(CUST_HOLD))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(HOLD))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(TypeName = "Data2")]
public class Root2
{

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("CUST_HOLD")]
    public CUST_HOLD[] CUST_HOLD;


     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("HOLD")]
    public HOLD[] HOLD;

}

 [Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType("CUST_HOLD")]
public class CUST_HOLD
{

    public int i;
}

[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType("HOLD")]
public class HOLD
{

    public int i;
}
```

**Serialization**

```
List<Root2> list = new List<Root2>();
Root2 obj = new Root2();
obj.CUST_HOLD = new CUST_HOLD[] { new CUST_HOLD() { i = 1 }, new CUST_HOLD() { i = 1 }, new CUST_HOLD() { i = 1 } };
obj.HOLD = new HOLD[] { new HOLD() { i = 1 }, new HOLD() { i = 1 }, new HOLD() { i = 1 } };

  list.Add(obj);

 //Serialize List<Root2>
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer = new     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Root2>),new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Root2"));

 System.IO.MemoryStream mo = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
 Serializer.Serialize(mo, list);
 string str = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(mo.ToArray());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Data2>
<CUST_HOLD>
  <CUST_HOLD>
    <i>1</i>
  </CUST_HOLD>
  <CUST_HOLD>
    <i>1</i>
  </CUST_HOLD>
  <CUST_HOLD>
    <i>1</i>
  </CUST_HOLD>
</CUST_HOLD>
<HOLD>
  <HOLD>
    <i>1</i>
  </HOLD>
  <HOLD>
    <i>1</i>
  </HOLD>
  <HOLD>
    <i>1</i>
  </HOLD>
</HOLD>
</Data2>
</Root2>
```

**DeSerialization**

```
string str = @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Root2 xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
<Data2>
<CUST_HOLD>
  <CUST_HOLD>
    <i>1</i>
  </CUST_HOLD>
  <CUST_HOLD>
    <i>1</i>
  </CUST_HOLD>
  <CUST_HOLD>
    <i>1</i>
  </CUST_HOLD>
</CUST_HOLD>
<HOLD>
  <HOLD>
    <i>1</i>
  </HOLD>
  <HOLD>
    <i>1</i>
  </HOLD>
  <HOLD>
    <i>1</i>
  </HOLD>
</HOLD>
</Data2>
</Root2>";

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Root2>), new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Root2"));

System.IO.MemoryStream mo = new   System.IO.MemoryStream(UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));

List<Root2> list = (List<Root2>)Serializer .Deserialize(mo);
```

**NOTE** `<Data2>` tag only appear if serialization type is `List<Root2>` for single `Root2` instance `<Data2>` tag will not displayed in xml string and Deserialization can not done. Deserialization will return null value for `CUST_HOLD` & `HOLD`. Return type should be `List<Root2>`.